# Is there a way to control your identity as a note-leaver/commenter on Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr

I have two Tumblr blogs within one account. Each blog has a URL in the form of **somename**.tumblr.com and a portrait photo.

If I "like" or respond to someone's post, is there a way I can select which blog the response appears to come from?

So what I'm saying is can I select which of my blog URLs and portrait photos I appear as in the list of notes?

Or is it that you have one "main" blog and that's always who you appear to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's ALWAYS the main blog only. The same reason you can't separate the likes linked to main and secondary blogs. When in doubt, always start a separate account (as irritating as it may be).